# How to insert a data in a table wherein one column name is a primary key of another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently developing an information system wherein the user needs to fill up a form,

I have two tables namely: `employee` and `insurance_company`.
In the employee table I have a column name named `insurance_id` wherein it is a primary key of the table insurance_company.

my problem is , I can insert data in the columns of employee table except for the insurance_id column but there is a data in the insurance_company table.

below is the form 
[image]

Comment: Before inserting values in `employee` table, get `insurance id` from `insurance_company` table. Use this value in your insert query to `employee` table.

Comment: What is the code you are trying to insert? or are you using triggers?

Comment: Thanks, @Samir. I'll do that.